# How to set the width of TextItem in DynamicForm

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

How to set the width of `TextItem` in `DynamicForm`?

Method `TextItem#setWidth()` is not working as expected.

I have tried `DynamicForm#setColWidths()` also but still unable to set the width.

Here is my code

```
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Window;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.DynamicForm;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.TextItem;

public class AgeModelWindow extends Window {

public AgeModelWindow() {
    TextItem textItem = new TextItem();
    textItem.setWidth(50);
    textItem.setLength(3);
    textItem.setTitle("Age");

    DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();
    form.setNumCols(2);
    //form.setColWidths("*", "50");
    form.setWidth100();
    form.setItems(textItem);

    this.setMargin(10);
    this.setTitle("Enter your age");

    this.addItem(form);

    this.setWidth(200);
    this.setHeight(100);
    this.setLeft(100);
    this.setTop(100);

    this.draw();
}

}
```

Comment: Removing `form.setColWidths("*", "10");` should fix this issue.

Comment: I am using SmartClient version v9.0p_2013-09-22/PowerEdition Deployment (built 2013-09-22) and GWT version 2.5. It's not working after removing setColWidths.

Comment: What width does `textItem` take?

Comment: By default textItem has width 200px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue using css styling on textItem. I don't know why it's not working via code in SmartGWT.

**code:**

```
textItem.setCellStyle("textItemAge");
```

**css:**

```
.textItemAge input,.textItemAgeFocused input,.textItemAgeDisabled input,.textItemAgeDisabledHint input,.textItemAgeError input,.textItemAgeHint input 
{ 
    width: 50px !important; 
}
```